# Academic with fellowship cannot land a permanent position in her department. Should she stay or move elsewhere?

Tags: funding, tenure-track

My PhD supervisor who I consider a friend is hoping to get a foothold on the academic ladder at a presitgious univeristy in the UK. She's held a fellowship for several years now and has a few more to go before it runs out. During this time she managed to build a pretty sizeable research group, is teaching her own course to good feedback and her publication record is on par with, if not better than, other junior academics recently employed by her department. However, despite applying for several junior vacancies at her department where she wants to stay, she hasn't come close to getting one. I can't think of many reasons why other than perhaps her field is not considered sexy enough and the department wants to get rid of it altogether.

I want to bring this up next time I see her. It seems it would make sense for her to jump ship and land a position elsewhere while she still holds the fellowship as I'm sure many other departments elsewhere would be glad to have her. On the other hand that's a bit unfair to her students and it may split the research group. If only a hendful of people agree to go with her, this also means that it would take her a while to get back on her feet after the move. Has anyone been in a similar situation and has any advice? Are there other less obvious reasons why a university would snub someone with a good track record who's bringing funding to the table?

Comment: " a bit unfair to her students" Unless she made a definite commitment that she will stay around, this is fair game, and one of the risks you accept when you join a research group (especially with a nontenured supervisor).

Comment: You are her subordinate, correct?  I would refrain from getting involved in anything regarding her career security; that's her business, not yours.  I'm sure she knows what she's up against.

Comment: @artificial_moonlet She was my supervisor but I'm outside the academia now and I consider her a good friend.

Comment: @lighthouse keeper Technically true but they may not be fully aware of the risks. I certainly wasn't thinking about this when I was applying for a PhD.

Comment: Given the vagaries of the academic job market, anyone whose contract expires within 'a few' years ought to be applying for anything that comes up. Serious external offers may also focus the current department's attention on whether they really want to lose her.

Comment: @Vibex I believe that for any major career decision, it's your responsibility to inform yourself about the potential risks involved. A departing supervisor is a common risk in academia.

Comment: This should be her question to ask on here.

Comment: If she has a sizable research group and is doing good teaching, it sounds as though she's an asset to her department. Perhaps they are relying on her while using rolling fixed-term contracts to keep costs low (especially if she has a fellowship that pays her salary). Possibly *she* should be having a conversation with them that amounts (not in this language) to "give me a non-fixed-term position or I'll look for one elsewhere". Ultimately, though, it's probably too specific and individual a question to work well for this site.

Answer (score 3):

Universities in the West are generally quite reluctant to hire anyone into permanent positions who had been graduate students or postdocs or otherwise temporary employees at that same university. This is fundamentally based on the idea that we don't want "inbreeding" of ideas and that it benefits departments and universities to get in people with other perspectives. As a consequence, there may not be merit-based reasons why she isn't hired -- it may all be due to not wanting to hire your own disciples.

The solution is of course to go elsewhere -- as almost all of us had to do at some point. Everyone understands that to be the system, and students need to know it as well. In many cases, one can make practical arrangements where students come along, or where someone who leaves can still advise students at their old university until they are graduated. (I have done both.)

Comment: Given that this stated to be the UK and the fellow has been in the position to build a group, the fellowship in question is most-likely a "5-year" fellowship like the Royal Society URF (or similar). These fellowships typically come with the expectation that the fellow is considered for permanent employment.

Comment: You are right about this. Universities hate hiring their own grads. I have heard this expressed in a less kind way though. "We taught you, so we *know* what's wrong with you. It's us!"

Comment: This makes sense and I something I haven't considered. I suppose it is also difficult for a department to turn away someone who's got their own funding even if that means leading them on (@mmeent's comment).